# Setting a 2d char array of spaces

Tags: c++, arrays, class, 2d, private

I am trying to initialize a 2d char array in the constructor of a class. The constructor is suppose to simply set the values of the char array to spaces: ' '. However trying this results in a SegFault.

Constructor:

```
Board::Board(void)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;i<10;j++)
        {
            score[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

where score is a private class member and a 10 by 10 char array.

Comment: It might help to tell us what language you are using.

Comment: I know i dont, i added it when trying to fix the error, it had no effect

Comment: You've put `i<10` in the second loop instead of `j<10`.

Comment: Did you step through this in the debugger? I like to do that while thinking through what should be happening. I think you will spot this sort of mistake fairly quickly if you do this. Tends to work for me anyway. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your program.

Here is the final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    char score[10][10];
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        for (j=0; j<10; j++){
            score[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see it getting compiled [here](http://ideone.com/uuCzUw)

## Mistakes:

1. <strike>You have not declared score, (`char score[10][10];`)</strike>
2. In line `for (j=0;i<10;j++)` you are incrementing variable `j` but checking for variable `i` so it will go into a infinite loop
3. There is no need for the line (`j=0;`)
4. `score[i][j] = ;` is not correct and it should rather be `score[i][j] = ' ';`

[I see you have corrected 2nd and 4th points in an update, they should rather be in the answer so that people don't get confused, so I will try to update the question once]

Comment: @ooga it would not skip, as see in the first case i would be 0 then it would enter the second loop as 0<10 and it will thus be in an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks my problem was that i in the second for loop, didnt catch it thank you!

Comment: replace both loops with `std::memset(&score, ' ', sizeof score);` -- that is of course if you don't switch to `std::array` which would be preferable